# Web Audio api : How to increase continuously the volume of the sound from the beginning

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In order to not chock the listener I want to play a wave but the volume should not be played at 100% ratio from early, it should go from 0% to 100% in duration of 2secondes for instance.

I tought of a setTimeout and I increase the gain by the time, but I don't know if is there any other better approch

```
    var source = aCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buf;
    var gainNode = aCtx.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = 0
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(aCtx.destination);
    source.start(0);

setTimeout(function() {
     gainNode.gain.value = 0.5
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function() {
     gainNode.gain.value = 1
}, 2000)
```

Comment: You should probably do it more than twice. And note, as it is written now, you audio remains silent of half a second and then explodes to 50% gain.

Comment: yes right, I tought of a loop of setTimeout depending of the step I am fixing

Comment: Yes, add some small gain and reschedule amplification until gain reaches 1.0 (or slightly below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Web Audio API provides a [library function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) for this.

```
AudioParam.linearRampToValueAtTime(value, endTime)
```

**value**

A floating point number representing the value the AudioParam will ramp to by the given time.

**endTime**

A double representing the exact time (in seconds) after the ramping starts that the changing of the value will stop.

---

So in your case use

```
gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, 0)
gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, 2)
```

Comment: thank you, I did not know that. But gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, 2) did not work for me at the first place even if I did gainNode.gain.value = 0. I had to add gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime); and then gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime + 2) like in the link. Thank you again you saved my day

Comment: @MehdiSouregi alright, thanks, didnt know that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Make it dynamic by simply using some kind of lerp function, there are many out there. The basic idea is that you get a value being interpolated between two of your starting values.
Example:

value 1 = 5

value 2 = 1

interpolation amount = 0.4 (40%)

then the result should be exactly 2.6

said function might just look like this

```
Math.lerp = function (value1, value2, amount) {
    amount = amount < 0 ? 0 : amount;
    amount = amount > 1 ? 1 : amount;
    return value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount;
};
```

In your specific scenario you would take the min and max volume as the both values and then regulate the amount using the time that has passed. Probably with some async function call back to this function.
hope i could help.